# Was the Zilog Z8070 ever mass produced?

Tags: zilog

I only recently came across a mention of the Z8070 FPU for the Z8000 family. According to some benches, it was very fast given its HMOS implementation and clock.

Of the very little information I can find on it, one web page suggests it never made it into production. Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: AFAIK the design was rather buggy, got never fully finished and stomped together with the Z80000. Although I once been told the Mil-version (Z16C70)  was delivered.

Comment: @Raffzahn - C for CMOS?

Comment: Just found some Z8000 info at https://www.kranenborg.org/z8000/. As of 2003, the Z16C01 was in production as a CMOS Z8001, and the  Z16C02 as a CMOS Z8002. Those had been in production since 1995 for "non-commercial embedded applications." The Z8070 FPU was apparently dropped early in the design phase.

Comment: There's a preliminary device specification for the Z8070 in the 1985 Zilog Data Book at. http://www.bitsavers.org/components/zilog/_dataBooks/ That says it can do a single-precision multiply in 28 clocks at 10MHz, which isn't all that impressive. It looks intended to compete with the 8087, naturally enough. It has one significant improvement in that the floating-point registers are individually addressable, rather than forming a small stack, but apart from that, it looks rather complicated to use.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz yes, the 16Cxx series was CMOS. Mut more important was the MIL-Spec temperature range and durability.

Comment: @JohnDallman Yes, the 8070 was based on memory mapped registers. But I would rather think of that inferior to a stack, as it needs memory to memory moves, which are by nature slower than memory register, longer opcodes, as it needs to encode the register to be used, and register specific move instructions instead of a single interface.  So while a register file in a CPU _may_ have less disadvantages than having them memory mapped, a stack will almost always perform equal or better due the automated memory management.

Comment: @Raffzahn: At the time, a register stack would not have been a disadvantage. But by the mid-1990s, it became a problem for Intel, because data on a stack that is being pushed and popped has strong mutual dependencies, making it hard to execute several x87 instructions at the same time. The main performance benefit of SSE2 came from the individual addressability of the registers. *not* from executing pairs of operations in a single instruction.

Comment: @JohnDallman I can only agree in part, as for one the 87 can quite well operate as register set, but equally important SSE is not a classic FPU application, but rather DSP style data streaming, isn't it? An area where memory mapped is even more of a show stopper than being integrated. That kind of operation wasn't really on the radar for a mainstream CPU until the very late 1980s to early 1990.

Comment: SSE was intended for streaming data, yes. SSE**2** added a full set of floating-point operations, and using them could produce significant speedups: I got +30% throughput just for changing a compiler switch (and working around a few new compiler bugs). The SSE2 operations are the standard floating-point for x86-64, where an x87 is always present, but ignoring it is wise.